# Htmlparser2 parse to get links and then parse those links (node.js)

Tags: json, node.js, parsing, html-parsing, html-parser

I'm using htmlparser2 in nodejs to parse a HTML page. I parse one page to get the links to other pages. Then I would like to parse those links (parsing function is not the same as on the first parsed page) to get some other information that I need beside that links.
My problem is that I do not know how to parse multiple pages. If I put links in array then loop through it and call parser for each page, it just doesn't work because of asynchronous nature. Even if i called multiple requests in for loop, it wouldn't parse all links and I'm still stuck with a problem of getting request result out of the actual request.

```
request(link,function(error,response,body)
{
        var obj = parsingData(body); //parsingData is my parsing function


        for(var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++){
            var newLink = obj[i].link;

            request(newLink,function(error,response,body)
            {
                    var pObj = parsingPasma(body);
                    console.log(pObj);
            }

            });
        //how would I get pObj here, to update obj array + wait for the request to finish?
        }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

async.js can help you manage asynchronous code easily. In this case you want to run some code after another async function finishes so you can easily use the waterfall function of async.js. Information is available here: https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#waterfall